# How to show a notification when app is closed (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, notifications

In my app, I am downloading data using the Facebook graph api and wish to present a notification when new data is available. I want to download data, compare it with what's already stored in NSUserDefaults and show a notification if it is different.

I allowed background fetch in the info.plist file and in my appDelegate, I have added the following code:

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions():

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(30)
```

In performFetchWithCompletionHandler()

(this doesn't include the code to check if the fetched data is new, it's just a test)

```
    let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/109315262061/posts?limit=20&fields=id,full_picture,picture,from,shares,attachments,message,object_id,link,created_time,comments.limit(0).summary(true),likes.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=\(API_KEY)"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

                do
                {
                    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)

                    ids.removeAll()

                    if let items = jsonData["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                    {
                        for item in items
                        {
                            if let id = item["id"] as? String
                            {
                                ids.append(id)
                            }
                        }
                        if ids.count == 20
                        {
                            print(jsonData)

                            let notification = UILocalNotification()
                            notification.alertBody = "You have new notifications!"
                            notification.alertTitle = "NSITConnect"
                            notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

                            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            })
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

The downloading operation occurs successfully but I don't see a notification. How can I fix this? Also is there a way to download data when the app is force closed and then display the notification? My apologies if this is a silly question, I am fairly new to this concept!

Comment: Notifications aren't shown if the app is already open, try creating an alert to display your message, or create a custom controller/view.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications aren't shown if the app is already open, try creating an alert to display your message, or create a custom controller/view.

You can check wether your app is currently active or not like this, and then either create the notification or the alert/custom controller.

```
application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active
```